# Creating a photo gallery in Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco

I'm new to Umbraco. I'm looking for a way to create a photo gallery in Umbraco 7.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One way that you could do it is to add a multiple media picker to your Document Type and that would allow your editors to select multiple images to be displayed in a gallery. You can then add either some Razor directly into the View for your Document Type to display the image gallery, or add it as a partial if you want to use it on several different Views.

Comment: There's also a gallery macro built in, if you create a new Razor Partial Macro, one of the options is "Gallery".